# Running a Rubik's Cube Solver from Github

Tags: windows, github, gcc, compilation, codeblocks

I am a student without any coding experience at all. I need to run this code on github, https://github.com/benbotto/rubiks-cube-cracker.git but I have no idea what I'm doing and I'm really just looking for any way to get this program running. I'm pretty sure the code is in c++, and the original device was a Linux. I'm trying to run it on a windows laptop, so please let me know of programs that I could use that are compatible. If anyone has any tips or just an in depth tutorial on how to get this running you would be a life saver. And please let me know if you need anymore details.

I've tried on VS code and Code::Block but I seem to just be running into errors like "fatal error glm/glm.hpp: no such file or directory" on code:block, and frankly, on VS Code I just had no idea what I was even trying to do.

Comment: What exactly did you try in VS code? If you want to get some C++ source code compiled into an executable, you need at least some experience in C++. Please consider to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the stackoverflow `Help Center / asking`. You should at least include in your question what you have tried so far and where you got stuck.